# Processing text file or string variable with foreign language characters

Tags: xml, vba, encoding, utf-8

I would like to use VBA functions for example `LCase$()` and next `UCase()` with my test.xml file which is UTF-8 encoded. The sample code that is below loads the file with UTF-8 content:

```
Dim objFileSystem, objInputFile

Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
Set objInputFile = 
objFileSystem.OpenTextFile("c:\test.xml", 1)

inputData = objInputFile.ReadAll

objInputFile.Close
```

Now I try to convert contents to lowercase and next change the first letter to upper case

```
Var = inputData
Var = LCase$(Var)

Select Case Len(Var)

Case 0
CapitilizeFirstLetter = ""

Case 1
CapitilizeFirstLetter = UCase(Var)

Case Else
CapitilizeFirstLetter = Ucase(Left(Var, 1)) & mid(Var, 2)

End Select
```

I try to save file contents under the name test_edited.xml

```
FileUrl = "c:\test_edited.xml"

Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
With objStream
    .Open
    .Charset = "utf-8" 'rosyjski iso-8859-5
    .Position = objStream.Size
    .WriteText=Var
    .Flush
    .Position = 0
    .Type     = 1 'binary
    .Read(3)      'skip BOM
    .SaveToFile FileUrl,2
    .Close
End With
Set objStream = Nothing
```

As a result, the content of the first file was:

> Nejznámější ŽENY, MODELY, herečka, zpěvačka

And the second one is now

> NejznĂˇmÄ›jĹˇĂ­ Ĺ˝ENY, MODELY, hereÄŤka, zpÄ›vaÄŤka

And I expected that it will look like that

> Nejznámější ženy, modely, herečka, zpěvačka

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Basic IDE ver 6.4.

The all code should be like below

```
Sub Main

'getting variable from outside
ChanNum = DDEInitiate("MacroEngine", "MacroGetVar")
Var$ = DDERequest$(ChanNum, "vChannelOpisA")
    DDETerminate ChanNum


Var = LCase$(Var) ' converting utf-8 encoded string to lower case

'change first letter to upper case
Select Case Len(Var)

Case 0
CapitilizeFirstLetter = ""

Case 1
CapitilizeFirstLetter = UCase(Var)

Case Else
CapitilizeFirstLetter = Ucase(Left(Var, 1)) & mid(Var, 2)

End Select

'sending variable to outside of vb script
ChanNum = DDEInitiate("MacroEngine","MacroSetVar")
Var = "vChannelOpisA=" + CapitilizeFirstLetter
DDEExecute (ChanNum, Var)
DDETerminate ChanNum

End Sub
```

The variable named Var should be utf-8 encoded finally to write them as a xml file. 
I can read a string from a file as well instead getting them with DDERequest.

Comment: It seems that some part of the code is changing characters codepage. Maybe I have to make different declaration of some variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my experience Vba utf-8, iso 8859-1 can be tricky as it depends on the file source editor and system environment if unix or windows or mac... Most text source editor or system use ANSI. I would advise you to try adodb as might read and renders utf-8 and the other one write better utf-8.

```
...
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
...
Dim ftxt As object
...

const bufFile = "c:\test.xml"
const stf = "c:\test_edited.xml"
Dim vData As Variant
Dim ftxt As TextStream
'ADODB
adoRead.Charset = "unicode"
adoRead.Open
adoRead.LoadFromFile bufFile
vData = Split(adoRead.ReadText, vbCrLf)
'ado object to write
Set fil = fso.GetFile(stf)
Set ftxt = fil.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting, TristateUseDefault)

'process your data as intended
For j = LBound(vData) To UBound(vData)
   'code to capitalize...
   '...
   'write to
   ftxt.WriteLine vData(j)
Next j
```

This structure worked for me on French characters, I think it should be the same within utf-8 or unicode character set.

Cheers

Pascal

Comment: The code above not working in my Basic environment and give my a fail TextStream (0) Expecting a valid data type (eg. Integer). I' got Sax Basic Edition, Basic IDE -Standard Edition

Comment: It has to do with the late binding of .net objects. Following your code above Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream"), it should work with 'dim ftxt as object'

Comment: What do you mean Pascal change to create. Can you edit your code about and show me how to do it. And how to insert example of capitalize code please.

Comment: it's getting late here, London, UK. I have amended the code above from  your request but it's difficult because it doesn't seem you provide the entire code you try to run yourself. Please post your code all together in one piece (from the start to the end) so to make it work from there.

Comment: See my edited code Pascal in your free time. It is very important to me. I need working code to continue my main job. So thanks for every your tips.

Comment: Hi Kassprek, the tag for this post mentions vba, everything looks like it's vba but it seems you're running code using DDERequest. I am not really used to this method. Can you access Excel and run everything from there as Vba is a ms office host application. From there, it'll make things easier. Also, the file as it's encoded at the source does matter. You should put a link where we can download your file. If you can't access vba from excel, maybe you can run everything as vbscript (vbs) it can do the same thing under windows as vba.

Comment: I am not gut in vba or vbs but I tried to run my code under vbs and it doesn't working. I'm working with some macro engine which can translate my website to other languages. Now I'm trying to generate rss channel. I have problem with random upper case letters appearing . My program for making macros can't working with utf-8 string but I can put vba, vbs script inside the macro code and send string variable to them or save them as utf-8 encoded file. So finally I must work with build-in basic script in my macro somehow. The xml file is utf8 for sure because it's working on my website fine.

Comment: this is the link to my rss channel and the result when I try to convert letter to lower case with vba - second line of the rss channel title first part of the text http://topmodels-photos.com/cz_rss.xml

Answer (score 3):

After 3 days my hard work and researchs I got it finally.
My program for creating Macros is working under windows-1250 charset as you can see.
So I must convert my string to utf-8 first and for the end convert back to windows-1250.
The correct code that works for me is given below.

```
Sub Main

' Retriving variable from outside vba
ChanNum = DDEInitiate("MacroEngine", "MacroGetVar")
Var$ = DDERequest$(ChanNum, "vChannelOpisA")
DDETerminate ChanNum


Dim objStream As Object

' Converting string variable from Windows-1250 to utf-8
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Open
objStream.Type     = 2 'Specify stream type text data.
objStream.Charset  = "WIndows-1250" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
objStream.WriteText Var
objStream.Position = 0
objStream.Charset  = "utf-8"
Var = objStream.ReadText
objStream.Close


' Processing the string characters to lower case and change first letter to upper case
Var = LCase$(Var)

Select Case Len(Var)
Case 0
CapitilizeFirstLetter = ""
Case 1
CapitilizeFirstLetter = UCase(Var)
Case Else
CapitilizeFirstLetter = Ucase(Left(Var, 1)) & mid(Var, 2)
End Select

' Converting edited string back to WIndows-1250.
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Open
objStream.Type     = 2 'Specify stream type text data.
objStream.Charset  = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
objStream.WriteText CapitilizeFirstLetter
objStream.Position = 0
objStream.Charset  = "WIndows-1250"
CapitilizeFirstLetter = objStream.ReadText
objStream.Close

' Sending string variable to my Macro engine
ChanNum = DDEInitiate("MacroEngine","MacroSetVar")
Var = "vChannelOpisA=" + CapitilizeFirstLetter
DDEExecute (ChanNum, Var)
DDETerminate ChanNum

End Sub
```

And here an example if you want load data for variable from file.

```
Sub Main

sFileToEdit = "c:\test.xml"
sFileEdited = "c:\test_edited.xml"


Dim objStream As Object

Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = 2 'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
objStream.Charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
objStream.Open 'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
objStream.LoadFromFile sFileToEdit
ReadFileData = objStream.ReadText
objStream.Close

ReadFileData = LCase$(ReadFileData)

Select Case Len(ReadFileData)
Case 0
CapitilizeFirstLetter = ""
Case 1
CapitilizeFirstLetter = UCase(ReadFileData)
Case Else
CapitilizeFirstLetter = Ucase(Left(ReadFileData, 1)) & mid(ReadFileData, 2)
End Select


Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = 2 'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
objStream.Charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
objStream.Open 'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
objStream.WriteText CapitilizeFirstLetter
objStream.SaveToFile sFileEdited, 2 'Save binary data To disk
objStream.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: sorry for not being able to help you further after we exchanged comments. a few things to care... anyway this is a nice code, it would have taken me long time to get there. well done